# custom button component + tailwind styles being purged

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, css-purge

I want to create a button component like this:

```
    function Button ({ color }) {
      return (
       <button  className={`hover:bg-${color}-300 bg-${color}-100>
     
       </button>
```

That way I can make all of my button colors (with hover variant) consistent by just doing:

```
<Button color="green" >

</Button>
```

The problem is that purge doesn't see that I want a green button so no styling occurs when I use purge.

Is there a better way to create my button component that will comply with CSS purge?

Comment: You can't concatenate style names like that and have them picked up. You'll need to safelist every possible class you want to use this way. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production#safelisting-specific-classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
  <button type={type} title={title} disabled={disabled} className={`
    active:drop-shadow-3xl
    select-none
    font-mono
    font-bold
    m-1.5
    p-1.5
    active:translate-y-[2px]
    border-2
    border-gray-400
    rounded-md
    ${className}`}
    onClick={click}>
      {children}
    </button>
```

and then add whatever inside of `${className}`.  its not a great answer but it is how I did it

Answer (score 1):

css get the the classes as them write in components but for this issue you need to use
`safelist: [{ pattern: /bg-(red|green|blue|sky)-(500)/, }, ],`
in **tailwind.config** to make them extract all time.

Comment: this is a good contribution but not a full solution